# An Insert algorithm test for a binary tree in Prolog

Tags: prolog, binary-tree

This is a homework question, i have pretty much the rest of the code done out, and the last part that i have to do is create an insert algorithm.

```
insert(I,T1,T2) - is true if T2 is the binary tree resulting from I being 
inserted into binary tree T1.
```

so far my code for this part is...

```
    insert(I,T1,T2) :- bTTree(T1(X,L,_), bTTree(T2(X,L,I).
    insert(I,T1,T2) :- bTTree(T1(nil,nil,nil),bTTree(T2(I,nil,nil).
    insert(I,T1,T2) :- bTTree(T1(X,L,_),bTTree(T2(X,L,I).
```

I don't know if i'm going in the right direction with this or not.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My completed Code (if you need it):

```
isempty(nil) :- !.
isempty(tree(nil,nil,nil)).

bTTree(tree(_,Left,Right)) :- binaryTree(Left), binaryTree(Right).
```

%traversals.

%preorder -- N,Left,Right

```
preorder(tree(N,_,_),N).
preorder(tree(_,Left,_),N) :- preorder(Left,N).
preorder(tree(_,_,Right),N) :- preorder(Right,N).
```

%inorder -- Left,N,Right.

```
inorder(tree(_,Left,_), N) :- inorder(Left,N).
inorder(tree(N,_,_), N).
inorder(tree(_,_,Right), N) :- inorder(Right,N).
```

%postorder -- Left,Right,N

```
postorder(tree(_,Left,_),N) :- postorder(Left,N).
postorder(tree(_,_,Right),N) :- postorder(Right,N).
postorder(tree(N,_,_),N).


search(t,I) :- bTTree(t(I,_,_)).
search(t,I) :- bTTree(t(_,I,_)).
search(t,I) :- bTTree(t(_,_,I)).
search(t,I) :- bTTree(t(_,N,_)), search(N,I).
search(t,I) :- bTTree(t(_,_,N)), search(N,I).


height(t,H) :- bTTree(t(nil,nil,nil)), H is 0.
height(t,H) :- bTTree(t(N,nil,nil)), H is 1.
height(t,H) :- bTTree(t(_,Left,Right)),
               height(Left, H1),
           height(Right, H2),
               H is max(H1,H2) + 1.

insert(I,t1,t2) :- bTTree(t1(X,L,_)),    
                   bTTree(t2(X,L,I)).
insert(I,t1,t2) :- bTTree(t1(nil,nil,nil)),
                   bTTree(t2(I,nil,nil)).
insert(I,t1,t2) :- bTTree(t1(X,L,_)),
                   bTTree(t2(X,L,I)).
```

Answer (score 0):

`bTTree(T1(X,L,_))` is a syntax error (apart in SWI-Prolog, after enabling the extension `set_prolog_flag(allow_variable_name_as_functor, true)` ).

Another problem is that bTTree/1 misses the base case, it will always fail after it completed the recursion. What's its purpose ? In Prolog usually functors are assumed as *formally* declared symbols, there is no point in having an 'indirection' like bBBtree/1 just to introduce a term like tree/3.

And of course, you should stick to the *same* representation for a data structure in a program: now you use `tree`, or `t`, or `t1`, or `t2`, ...

I think that before working on insertion those problems should be solved...